# Read only XmlDeclaration from the xml file

Tags: .net, xml

Is there an easy way to read only [XmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.aspx) from the xml file disregarding all the rest of it? Specifically I want to get declared encoding. The best thing I have now:

```
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(path))
    if (reader.Read() && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("encoding"));
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? It seems it does exactly what you want in a straightforward way.

Comment: @svick: I wonder whether there is some built-in functionality for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this page may help you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308061.
Scroll down to "The Encoding Property of the Readers" page, a little lower than halfway down the page. They have:

```
        // Reading the encoding using the reader classes.
        XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader("Q308061.xml");
        rdr.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Encoding from the reader: {0} \n\n", rdr.Encoding.EncodingName);
```

So I'm guessing, the reader includes a built in function for encoding, but the way you have is quite.. simplified and well done, not sure if there actually is an "easier" way to to do it. You could also tell the reader to stop reading by using the reader.close() function. That way, as soon as you hit the declaration, you get the encoding and you leave it.